# Start E-Mail client from setOnAction

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to send E-Mail when I click on a menu.

```
        MenuItem sendmail= new MenuItem("Send E-Mail");

        sendmail.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Call E-mail Client
            }
        });
```

Can you tell me how I can call e-mail client installed to the user PC from this code?

Answer (score 6):

This is undocumented, but appears to work, and is a "pure FX" solution rather than relying on java.awt APIs or knowing the location of external executables. Call the `Application.getHostServices().showDocument(...)` method and pass in a mailto: url as the url:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OpenDefaultBrowser extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final HBox root = new HBox(5);
        final TextField textField = new TextField("help@example.com");
        final Button goButton = new Button("Mail");

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> goHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:"+textField.getText());
            }

        };

        textField.setOnAction(goHandler);
        goButton.setOnAction(goHandler);

        root.getChildren().addAll(textField, goButton);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I stand corrected then. I will delete my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Desktop class.  I believe the code would look something like:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)) {
        URI mailto = new URI("mailto:john@example.com?subject=Hello%20World");
        desktop.mail(mailto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned from [@James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684876/2851311) example. In my case, I want users to email me in case there are issues with this app I developed. Because the email does not change, I thought it was best, ***for this specific case***, to include a JavaFX [Hyperlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html) to a "mail to" email address. The code is as follows:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("Report an issue");
alert.setHeaderText(null);

Text msg = new Text("For issues, email ");
Hyperlink emailLink = new Hyperlink("hector@foo.com");
emailLink.setOnAction(event -> {
    getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:" + emailLink.getText());
    alert.close(); // to dimiss the alert if user clicks hyperlink
});

TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(msg, emailLink);
DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
dialogPane.setContent(flow);
alert.showAndWait();
```

[image: My dialog]

This works fine if you have an email client like Outlook. We use Google Suite, which means we use Gmail. For Windows, if an email client is not installed, it will default to the Windows Mail app. I needed to open Gmail on the browser. So, I needed to change this on the Windows settings.

[image: Windows email settings]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to start a separate process which represents the e-mail client, use java.lang.Runtime.exec (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) or if you want the client to be embedded, use Java Mail API (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)